# How to turn off the ringtone programmatically?

Tags: ios

I want to turn off the ringtone. Otherwise, at least to decrease the sound of the ring tone and to stop the vibration of the device.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you’re targeting jailbroken devices and use private, undocumented APIs, you simply can’t.

Comment: Hi.,first thanks for the response.Now i am targeting jail broken devices.Can you please tell me how do this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that would be at the user's decision, not the developer's. Another example is screen brightness.

Comment: Screen brightness is settable via private API, iBooks does this. And if you take a look at iOS 5 release notes you might be surprised :)

Comment: @fichek - Still doesn't change the fact that you can't turn the ringer off programatically.

Comment: You are right about iBooks, I was thinking about that but I don't know if it's just API that Apple only has internally.